# Prove that $n^{55} = O(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

How can I prove that $n^{55} = O(2^n)$ using the following Big O definition:
$$
f(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \\
\Leftrightarrow
$$
there are positive constants $c$ and $n_0$, such that $|f(g(n))| \le c \cdot g(n)$, for all $n \ge n_0$.

I know that $n^c$ will always grow slower than $2^n.$

So we start with:
$$
10n^{55} \le c \cdot 2^n.
$$

Then, I used logarithms but without success :(

I also thought of some how turn the exponential function into a polynomial one, or vice versa, but as a computer science student, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You have the definition wrong - a first step  would be getting that straight. By definition $f(n)=O(g(n))$ if there exist $n_o$ and $c$ such that $|f(n)|\le c g(n)$ for all  $n>n_o$.

Comment: I'm going to slightly edit your question to make it more readable using LaTeX; by looking at my edits, you can learn how it's done. I'm not going to change the substance, though, so your wrong definition of big-O will remain until you fix it.

Comment: Thanks, you all for the tips! That was just my first question here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\left(1+\frac1{79}\right)^{55}<2$$

so that for all $n\ge79$,

$$\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{55}<2$$

and by the telescoping product, $n^{55}$ grows slower than $2^n$.